# cannot implicitly convert type string to char

Tags: c#, asp.net, business-logic, type-conversion

As I know char is different from string. I give datatype char to a column status in a table.
I am stuck here because i am using char first time. here is my code

```
 cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
        MySqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        List<clssessionprp> obj = new List<clssessionprp>();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            clssessionprp k = new clssessionprp();
            k.p_sescod = Convert.ToInt32(dr[0]);
            k.p_session = dr[1].ToString();
            k.p_status = dr[2].ToString();
        }
```

here status column is of char datatype. I google this but can't found any desired result.
any help will be appriciated

my BLL code is

```
public void save_rec(clsclsprp p)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("ins_cls", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.Add("_clsnam", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = p.p_clsnam;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("_clsdes", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = p.p_clsdes;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("_clssec", MySqlDbType.Char,1).Value = p.p_clssec;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: May I have a look at the "K" class?

Comment: its just datatype conversion problem answer below solved it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [Convert.ToChar(Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/609e20th%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to directly converting object to character instead of converting it to string using `ToString()`.

```
k.p_status = Convert.ToChar(dr[2]);
```

Comment: one more question adil, Char is not supported in mysqldbtype than should we change it or how to fix it ?

Comment: Do you get exception when you execute Convert.ToChar(dr[2]) ? what data it contains?

Comment: It work fine but when pass parameter in any method in my BLL. It says 'MySqlDbType does not contain a definition for Char' I am using Mysql with asp.net webforms

Comment: What if you convert char to string before you pass to MySQLDb or using some other appropriate type instead of string?

Comment: Can you try this, cmd.Parameters.Add("_clssec", MySqlDbType.String).Value = p.p_clssec.ToString();

Comment: it gives me no error but my char has size 1. is it correct to use String ?

Answer (score 3):

How about:

`dr[2].ToString()[0]` - checking that it is not null, of course.

Alternatively:

`Convert.ToChar(dr[2])` could work too.

Answer (score 2):

There are two options...

Convert.ToChar(dr[2]);

or

char chartext = text.ToCharArray()[0];

Answer (score 0):

What about this

```
   k.p_status  = char.Parse(dr[2].ToString());
```